# Pulling changes from GitHub on 2nd computer

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

If I am working on a project on one PC that's kept up to date in GitHub and I move to a different computer system to continue working on it, how do I pull only the changed files onto the second machine in VS Code without cloning the entire project again to continue working on it?

Comment: You don't.. why would cloning not work for you? If you need to isolate certain changed files, you commit and push them on another branch, then clone & pull that branch

Comment: ... `git pull`?

Comment: @webketje that what I was thinking.  The only reason I was asking is because my project (Angular and dotnet Core) has some SSL certificates that I need to reinstall every time I clone the project which is a bit annoying.  But if this is the way to do it then this is the way to do it.

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe, I'll look at this!!

Comment: You could use a `post-checkout` [git hook](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) command that does it automatically (curl fetch and exec a script like this one for Windows: https://www.manageengine.com/products/desktop-central/script-templates/computer-management/install-certificate.html